# Expected value with a die with 9 faces

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value, dice

> You have a die with $9$ faces, which are numbered $1, 2, 3, \dots,9$. All the numbers have an equal chance of appearing. You roll the die repeatedly, write the digits one after another, and you stop when you obtain a multiple of $3$. For example, you could roll a $4$, then a $1$, then a $7$. You would stop at this point, because $417$ is a multiple of $3$ but $4$ and $41$ are not. 
>  Find the expected number of times that you roll the die.

---

I'm not sure how to find the expected value of something, can I get a solution to this problem?

Comment: You should look up the definition of expected value.  The point of this question is to see if you understand and can apply it.  You also need to know the divisibility test for $3$.  The constant $9$ is chosen so you have $1/3$ chance of success each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that at any point, there are $3$ values from $1\to 9$ that would make the number a multiple of $3$ if rolled, since a number is a multiple of $3$ iff its sum of digits is.

If the sum of the currently rolled digits mod $3$ is $1$, then $2,5,8$ would make the number a multiple of $3$.

If the sum mod $3$ is $2$, then $1,4,7$ would make the number a multiple of $3$.

If this is the first roll, then $3,6,9$ would make the number a multiple of $3$.

So, the expected value is just $$\frac1{1/3}=3$$

Comment: I don't understand how your argument bypasses the need to calculate the probability of taking $n$ throws.

Comment: @RobArthan The probability of finishing in N trials is given by the geometric distribution, with p = 1/3. The expected value of the geometric distribution is 1/p. If an individual trial succeeds 1/3 of the time, it will take you on average 3 trials to get a success. If a trial succeeds 1/10 of the time, it will take you on average 10 trials to get a success.

Comment: Sure, I know that, but the question says the OP doesn't know how to calculate expectations.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: because the number will be divisible by 3 iff the sum of its digits is a multiple of 3, at each stage the probability of stopping is $1/3$ and the probability of having to roll again is $2/3$. The probability, $p_n$ say, of having to roll exactly $n$ times is therefore $(2/3)^{n-1}(1/3)$. The expected number of throws is then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}np_n$. To calculate this, you can use the formula for the sum of a geometric sequence to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}  = 1/(1-x)^2$.

Comment: That should be $x/(1-x)^2$, not $1/(1-x)^2$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. It now says what I meant to say.